# Applying the result of Cuthill-McKee in SciPy

Tags: algorithms, python, sparse-matrix, matrix, scipy

I have applied [SciPy](https://www.scipy.org)'s implementation of the [Cuthill-McKee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuthill%E2%80%93McKee_algorithm) algorithm to a $48 \times 48$ sparse **non**-symmetric matrix in Compressed Sparse Row (CSR) format and the output is an array of length $48$ which the documentation calls a "permutation array".

How do I use this "permutation" array?

Obviously, the array is in some way representing how my matrix is to be reordered, but a permutation array of length $48$ is only enough to reorder one axis. What am I missing?

Comment: Is your matrix symmetric and positive definite?  In that case you would normally apply the permutation symmetrically to both rows and columns of the matrix.

Comment: Positive definite, but not symmetric, but apparently scipy adds the matrix and its transpose to make it symmetric before applying RCM.

Comment: @BrianBorchers, I'm not aware that there is any requirement on positive definiteness to use RCM.  Is there a reason why you say this?  I thought it just needs to be symmetric in _structure_ for the algorithm to "make sense".

Comment: If you're going to use RCM with a sparse Cholesky factorization then the matrix needs to be positive definite.  That's the most common use-case.

Comment: Thanks, I see.  My only experience with RCM is in the context of reordering the nodes of a finite element mesh, and then you are really just thinking about how those nodes are "connected" on a graph and the values (in the context of the final assembled FE system) don't matter, from what I recall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reverse Cuthill-McKee algorithm produces a reordering that applies to both the rows and columns.  This is because it works by considering matrices as graphs of (undirected) connected nodes.  According to the function's [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.reverse_cuthill_mckee.html#scipy.sparse.csgraph.reverse_cuthill_mckee) in SciPy, the output array is the permuted row/column indices, so you can simply do the following

```
perm = reverse_cuthill_mckee(arr_orig)
arr_perm = arr_orig[perm, perm]
```

and numpy's fancy indexing functionality will take care of it.  Of course, this involves making a copy of your array, and I assume that's acceptable.

Comment: For larger sparse matrices it is much faster to apply the permutation directly to the sparse matrix index array: `mat.indices = perm.take(mat.indices)` than convert the matrix to csc: `mat = mat.tocsc()` and apply the permutation again: `mat.indices = perm.take(mat.indices)`. If you need the matrix in csr you can convert it back again. Using the advanced indexing is much slower than this - even when the matrix is converted twice between the formats. Tested with 25k x 25k matrices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if [Nick's answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/24820/) is right or maybe it was working in the previous version but it does not really in this one.

First of all, `reverse_cuthill_mckee` does not take a NumPy array as an input but it takes a `csr_matrix`.

I think it should be:

```py
arr = [
    [0, 1 , 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [2, 0, 0, 3],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]
    
graph = csr_matrix(arr)
perm = reverse_cuthill_mckee(graph)
reord_arr = csr_matrix.toarray(graph[perm])
```